# IBM MobileFirst Server 7.0 - Hydrib App-IOS9

Tags: ios9, ibm-mobilefirst

Dojo version :1.10.3 (ae6be82)
Java 7 MobileFirst platform Studio v7:7.0.0.00-20150907 -1450
Os:Ubuntu 14.4(64 bit)

After applying "7.0.0.0 MFPF-StudioP2-IF201509071450.zip Fix" fixpack, in (android environment)mobile adapters calls are failed it is not connecting to server, there is no error printed in console.log or message.log even trace.log

app is working fine in browser but getting an alert gap_init:2

Note : I recreated android environment and rebuild

Comment: Please do us the courtesy of providing the full error you're actually getting. Paste the Xcode Console log.

Comment: After applying fix pack the app is not working android also and we got an error get_initi2.

Comment: Did you read my comment? We cannot help if you ask questions like this. Do you want help?

Comment: we don't have any Xcode Console log because we are not running our application in mac at present

Comment: So why are you complaining about iOS if you cannot run your Xcode project? How exactly are you looking to get help this way? You've applied a Studio patch, now you need to re-build your project and re-run it in Xcode.

Comment: Dojo version :1.10.3 (ae6be82) Java 7 MobileFirst platform Studio v7:7.0.0.00-20150907 -1450 Os:Ubuntu 14.4(64 bit)

After applying "7.0.0.0 MFPF-StudioP2-IF201509071450.zip Fix" fixpack, in (android environment)mobile adapters calls are failed it is not connecting to server, there is no error printed in console.log or message.log even trace.log

app is working fine in browser but getting an alert gap_init:2

Note : I recreated android environment and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is in fact not related to the Android Emulator, but to previewing the Android environment in the MobileFirst Console's MBS. This happens due to a regression and is taken care of in *APAR PI50036 CORDOVA "GAP_INIT:2" ERROR WHEN PREVIEWING ANDROID IN MBS*.

---

This is very confusing and misinformed question, not to mention does not even provide clear information...

You say you have a problem with an app in iOS 9.
You say you've installed a Studio fix.
You say you do not have a Mac.

You need a Mac.
You need to re-build your MobileFirst project in the updated Studio.
You need to re-build the newly generated Xcode project, in Xcode, in Mac.

Once you do that, and if it still fails, provide the Xcode Console log.

Comment: Sorry i have problem in andriod environment.
I recreated android environment and rebuild. after applying fixpack.
getting an  alert Gap_init:2 in browser but app is connecting to server but facing problem in mobile it is not connecting to server and no alert in mobile

Comment: Post the application code you are using and the logcat log.